# PDFCreator installation crash

Tags: pdf, installation, crash, windows-7-x64

I am currently trying to install PDFCreator 1.6.2 on my computer (Windows 7 64bits).
I have to use this specific version and not another one due to compatibility issues with another program.

- I launch the setup in administrator mode, check "Expert settings"
- I accept the agreements
- I choose the Server Installation
- I Click on "next", let the default printer's name "PDFCreator"
- I do not check the box "Windows 2000/XP/2003 - 32bit" and click next
- I choose the directory in which I want to install it (C:...\PDFCreator)
- I just uncheck "PDFArchitect" and let everything else by default
- I let the program's shortcut name in the start ùmenu folder by default (PDFCreator)
- At the next page I also let everything by default (create a desktop icon for all users, create an entry in the Windows Explorer context menu)
- Click on next, the summary of the installation is displayed, click on Install
- The bar goes through the end, then "Create an entry in the Windows Explorer context menu" is displayed and a error pop-up appears which says "During the printer installation errors have occured. A detailed description can be found in the file "SetupLog.txt" in application path.
- I click on "OK", and the last setup page is displayed. I uncheck all the boxes (launch PDFCreator, SetupLog.txt, show help), click finish and the setup crashes.

PDFCreator does not appear in the printers and if I try to add one manually by clicking on "add a printer", select "add a local printer", "create a new port", port type : "pdfcmon", I can click on "next" but it has no effect so I am a bit stuck.

Do you have an idea why does the installation crashes ? 
Is there a workaround ?

The content of the file "SetupLog.txt" is available here : 
[SetupLog.txt](http://textup.fr/150656vz)

Comment: Nevermind, I gave up installing PDFCreator, I have a server on which I could install it without any problem so the problem is kinda fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I gave up installing PDFCreator, I have a server on which I could install it without any problem so the problem is kinda fixed

I still don't know why it crashed but that's not relevant anymore.

Sorry for making some of you wasting their time

Answer (score 1):

I've so far been unable to reproduce your problem despite numerous test installs (and uninstalls) of v1.6.2 on a Win7 64-bit box. Your posted log indicates that the process successfully created the pdfcmon port, but then apparently lost it afterwards (or else never created it, but misread its own return status):

```
    Install printerport:
    Portname : pdfcmon
     Result: Success
    [...]
    InstallPrinter:
     Printername: PDFCreator
     Drivername : PDFCreator
    Portname : pdfcmon
     Result: Error 1796 = Le port spécifié est inconnu
```

It's reasonable to assume that nothing useful will occur beyond that point, so you'll need to address error 1796 first. A quick Google of that error code leads to a number of queries at PDFForge.org about it:

http://forums.pdfforge.org/search?Search=1796

Not all received replies, but one involving 2003 Server in particular did:

> you need the latest service pack for Server 2003, then it should work.

Elsewhere in your log file I see references to some older software (e.g. Internet Explorer version: 9?) which leads me to think that you might want to doublecheck that all your relevant service packs and software are up to date first, then try your installation again.

Comment: Aere you sure I can install the latest service pack for Server 2003 on my W7 computer ?
On the Microsoft website ([link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10018), in the system requirements the supported OS are Windows Server 2003 R2 x64 editions, Windows Server 2003 x64 editions and Windows XP Professional x64 Edition, there is not Windows 7 64bits ?